# lwgl textures multiple binding to one VBO

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, vbo

I have a array(height map) and want to render it but I want different texture for each "square", can I do it with one VBO for vertices and second VBO for texture?

Is good idea to split that array into smaller parts.
what size is best? I read somewhere 32*32?, or 16*16 like Minecraft?

I want to I can change height in array, while program run and render change, what I must do?

Here is part of my program:

```
amountOfVertices = 6 * (data.length - 1) * (data[0].length - 1);

vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * vertexSize);
for (int z = 0; z < data.length - 1; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length-1; x++) {
        vertexData.put(new float[] { x, data[z+1][x], z+1, }); // Vertex
        vertexData.put(new float[] { x+1, data[z+1][x+1], z+1, }); // Vertex
        vertexData.put(new float[] { x+1, data[z][x+1], z, }); // Vertex

        vertexData.put(new float[] { x+1, data[z][x+1], z, }); // Vertex
        vertexData.put(new float[] { x, data[z][x], z, }); // Vertex
        vertexData.put(new float[] { x, data[z+1][x], z+1, }); // Vertex
    }
}
vertexData.flip();

textureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * texSize);
for (int z = 0; z < data.length - 1; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length-1; x++) {
                textureData.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, }); // Texture Coordinate
                textureData.put(new float[] { 1f, 0f, }); // Texture Coordinate
                textureData.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, }); // Texture Coordinate

                textureData.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, }); // Texture Coordinate
                textureData.put(new float[] { 0f, 1f, }); // Texture Coordinate
                textureData.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, }); // Texture Coordinate
    }
}
textureData.flip();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());

stone.bind();//bind a texture

vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


vboTexCoordHandle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTexCoordHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think to best way to solve your problem would be to use a texture map and still use the complete VBO, without dividing it into pieces. Having multiple tiles on one image is also faster, since binding a texture requires many resources. Anyway, try getting creating a tilemap. The texture coordinates would describe your texture then. So for example if you have 4 different textures of the same size you could put them all into one large 2x2 image. No, to bind the first texture to a quad, you could use the texture coordinates (0, 0) to (0.5, 0.5). The last texture would be bound on the coordinates (0.5, 0.5) to (1.0, 1.0). It is the best way that comes into my mind right now.